# Редирект вниз страницы

Tags: php, javascript

Не подскажете как сделать редирект вниз страницы? То есть, (отправляю сообщение) страница перезагружается, но при этом отправляет вниз страницы. Видел такое на php.

Answer (score 1):

Не видел такого на php.

Можно воспользоваться [якорями](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya) (не забудьте, что в html5 атрибут `name` больше не поддерживается).

Ну и очевидный вариант: скроллить страницу после загрузки `document.getElementById('id_подвала_или_еще_чего_нибудь').scrollIntoView()`

Comment: Не, якоря не подходят. Но они подойдут для решения другой проблемы.
А вот вариант скроллинга не плох. Спасибо :3

Comment: Вот только как мне прицепить его к форме, не подскажешь? Может условием? Типа if else? Или может так: 
<input type="submit" value="<?php echo $lang['SUBMIT']; ?> document.getElementById('.footer').scrollIntoView() />
?
А ничего, что у меня там класс, а не айди?

Comment: Если скроллить нужно сразу после загрузки, можно воспользоваться атрибутом `onload` в `<body>` (http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/onload). В вашем случае нужно использовать `getElementsByClassName('footer')` и не забыть, что она возвращает список элементов, даже если он один. В преддверии еще нескольких вопросов спешу порекомендовать умело воспользоваться гуглом.

Comment: Да я все понял. Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: Хммм, не работает.

Comment: @KaZaца: Метод getElementsByClassName(...) не кроссбраузерный.

    function getElementsByClassName(classname, node) {
        if (!node) node = document.body;
     var ret = [],
      re = new RegExp('(^| )' + classname + '( |$)'),
      els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for (var i=0, j = els.length; i < j; i++) {
            if (re.test(els[i].className)) ret.push(els[i]);
     } 
        return ret[0];
    }
  
    getElementsByClassName('footer').scrollIntoView();

@gm-111: Прививайте к себе дисциплину самостоятельности.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте при загрузке и каждом обновлении страницы следующий код JS:

el.scrollTop = Math.ceil(el.scrollHeight - el.clientHeight);

где el - элемент страницы, в котором следует выполнить скроллинг.